# get sum conditional with mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get the sells sum, just with the `idCategory`, any idea?
I have this 3 schemas in mongondb

```
category = [{"id":1,"name":"cat1"}, {"id":2,"name":"cat2"}]
product  = [{"id":1,"name":"product1", "catId":1}, {"id":2,"name":"product2", "catId":2}]
sells    = [{"id":1,"value":80, "productId":1, status:'active'},  {"id":2,"value":90, "productId":2, status:'Inactive'}]
```

Comment: No idea what you are saying. MongoDB collections are not arrays. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center and take a look at some of the questions asked by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB collections are not actual schemas, also, I'm assuming:

- You're interpreting them as arrays (although they aren't), so you mean each of your Collections have 2 documents inside of them.
- You want the sum of sales grouped by product category.

If those are the cases, what you want is a MongoDB Aggregate which you would run on your "sells" collection, "join" with the "product" collection and group by category id.

The base aggregate to do so would be along the following lines:

```
sells.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "product",
            localField: "productId",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "ProductData"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$ProductData"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ProductData.catId",
            total: { $sum: "$value" }
        }
    }
]);
```

If you also want to fetch the Category name after aggregating, all you need to do is insert another $lookup at the end of the pipeline joining with category collection:

```
sells.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "product",
            localField: "productId",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "ProductData"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$ProductData"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ProductData.catId",
            total: { $sum: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "category",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "CategoryData"
        }
    },
    { 
        $unwind: "$CategoryData"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$CategoryData.name",
            total: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

EDIT (adding new case request on comment):

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "sells",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "productId",
            as: "SalesData"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:
        {
            path: "$SalesData",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            catId: 1,
            value: "$SalesData.value"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$catId",
            total: { $sum: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "category",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "CategoryData"
        }
    },
    { 
        $unwind: "$CategoryData"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$CategoryData.name",
            total: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: hi @pedro-goes thanks, it works i have other question, with this method show me just if exist sells, but if i want see all the categories, with sells or not sells, do you know ?

Comment: hey @fernando, in order to do so what you will need is to change the order of the .aggregate. you will want to run it primarily on the "category" collection (so it fetches all categories) or the "product" collection (so it fetches all products) instead of the "sells" collection. from this points you will $lookup till you reach sales, and then proceed to group and such. It will probably need some adjusting but this is the path. I'll tinker with an example when I reach a working pc and update my answer.

Comment: i couldn't, better i will wait for your update, thanks

Comment: once again thank you, but still just show me one category not all the categories, currently show me the category that has sells asigned

Comment: I tested this with your data, just changing the second sale (the one with 90 value) to productId: 1 and worked fine. Showed me the category: 2 with 0 value. It returns:
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "total" : 0,
    "name" : "cat2"
}

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "total" : 170,
    "name" : "cat1"
}

Comment: yes it works, thanks, one last question for example i add a new value in sells like status=active/innactive and i need just the sells with status active ?